# liquibase delete row from databasechangelog

Tags: liquibase, delete-row

Is it OK to manually delete rows from Databasechangelog?

Btw, rollback to a TAG is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting rows from the table will simulate a rollback without actually performing one.... Leaving your database in an unknown state (the whole point is that liquibase manages the schema for you).

Why not just rollback a specified number of changesets instead?

```
liquibase rollbackCount 5
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The changeSets are saved in a file. The problem is that when I do a rollback on the tag in that file the rollback of the last two changeSets somehow do not take effect. It is about rolling back added columns with default values.  So I wanted to delete the row in the Databasechangelog and then drop the columns manually. Would this still leave the database in an unknown sate? I thought the database state will get back to where it was before performing the update in the file.

Comment: @mnish What you're doing will work provided you know exactly what you're doing. I'm concerned when you say the liquibase rollback did not work...

Comment: @MarkO'Connor can you have a look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230105/liquibase-empty-rollback-deletes-latest-row-from-databasechangelog